# Forcing non-cached gethostbyname()

Tags: c++, linux, caching

Is there any way to prevent the `gethostbyname()` function not to read the nscd cache on Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really an answer, but use `getaddrinfo(3)` instead :)
As far as `nscd` is concerned, here's from the `nscd.conf(5)` manual page:

```
enable-cache service <yes|no>
    Enables or disables the specified service cache.
```

You'll have to find out what the correct `service` for DNS is.

Comment: Thanks, it's been a while since I played with those :)

Comment: Thanks for the getaddrinfo() - it looks as it not being cached by nscd indeed (at least in man page)?


I prefer not to disable the cache at all, as it's only required for particular app.

Comment: Hi.

Can someone provide an example how to use getaddrinfo() to get the IP address?

Thanks.

Comment: Managed to get getaddrinfo() running from here:
http://cboard.cprogramming.com/windows-programming/16888-resolving-hostname-using-getaddrinfo-winsock.html

Answer (score 3):

Call `res_init()` before `gethostbyname()`. It seems ok.

Answer (score 1):

don't use nscd? :)

Seriously, if you're relying on `gethostbyname()` you may want to use `libresolv` and call `res_gethostbyname()` instead.

Although that is considered a security flaw by [djb](http://cr.yp.to/djbdns/res-disaster.html) at least :)

Consider using the [djbdns client library](http://cr.yp.to/djbdns/blurb/library.html).  Very secure, fast, and solid.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it looks somewhat old (2001)?

Also, any idea if it header-level library, or the libraries can be static-linked?

Comment: Yes it's old, but very solid.  I don't know about header level / static linking though, but the source is in the public domain so you could experiment with it.

Comment: And, it's no older than gethostbyname() :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think gethostbyname really caches entries. It's most likely your dns-cache itself.

Comment: Actually it uses nscd cache. The problem with this caused when the IP changes - it take A LOT (10 min by default) time the nscd refresh the cache and try to resolve it again.